# Create view with dynamically selected tables - is it possible?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have subsection of tables in my database that share part of a schema and a naming scheme. I'd like to create a view that automatically gathers all of the common columns of these tables into a single place. The catch is that more of these tables may be added from time to time, and I would ideally like to have the view dynamically add these new tables to itself.

For example, say we have three tables

```
+-----------------+ +-----------------+ +-----------------+
|table1           | |table2           | |table3           |
+-----------------+ +-----------------+ +-----------------+
|id               | |id               | |id               |
|name             | |name             | |name             |
|unique_attribute1| |unique_attribute2| |unique_attribute3|
+-----------------+ +-----------------+ +-----------------+
```

If I were doing this statically, I would write the view as:

```
CREATE VIEW unified_table_view AS
SELECT id, name FROM
  (SELECT id, name FROM table1)
  UNION (SELECT id, name FROM table2)
  UNION (SELECT id, name FROM table3);
```

However, if a new table

```
+-----------------+
|table4           |
+-----------------+
|id               |
|name             |
|unique_attribute4|
+-----------------+
```

is added and I want it to be included in the view, I would have to go an manually add that to the view definition:

```
CREATE VIEW unified_table_view AS
SELECT id, name FROM
  SELECT id, name FROM table1
  UNION SELECT id, name FROM table2
  UNION SELECT id, name FROM table3
  UNION SELECT id, name FROM table4;
```

**I want to know if it is possible to write the view such that when `table4` is added, the view automatically incorporates it, without me having to update the view definition.**

Normally if I was doing something like that, I would interrogate `information_schema` to construct something for `EXECUTE`, but that is a one-time thing and I would have to run the query again to update the view.

Comment: Setup a DDL trigger to check if your new table has been created then it can trigger some dynamic SQL that will add to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with a view, because a view is parsed when it is created, and the parse tree is stored. That will lead to an error if a table used in the view does not exist.

What you could do is to write a table function that searches for tables, constructs a query string for each and uses `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` to add the results to the output. That would be equivalent to `UNION ALL`. If you need `UNION`, you'd use `SELECT DISTINCT` to query the table function.